# In android UI is it possible to define gradient color on chip class?

Tags: android, xml, colors, background, gradient

I am using the class com.google.android.material.chip.ChipDrawable for defining input text field. I would like the default value to be shown in dark blue gradient color, However I didn't find a way to do that.
Usually gradient color is defined in drawable directory (with the high value and the lowest value the gradient).
in drawable directory:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
      android:startColor="#6586F0"
      android:endColor="#D6D6D6"
      android:angle="0" />

</shape>
```

and on the layout directory there should be something like:

```
android:background="@drawable/...."
```

[Desired chip with gradient](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfwQ3.png)

Comment: did u try to use that drawable as the background of the chip??

Comment: Yes, it is not effective. I get single color which is not related to the edge colors I specified

Comment: Could you please share the desired output, any reference image?

Comment: I added an image. Thanks

Comment: You can also use card view with round corners and use drawable as background. I think it may work for you Give it a shot.

Comment: @KamalNayan What about multiple similar views? I am adding chip programmatically and not able to give gradient background